# How do i invoke my api which is configured in Kong through web browser?

Tags: json, api, curl, kong

I have created a new API configuration through kong..(dummy API) as below.

curl -i -X POST \

> --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
>   --data 'name=myRESTapi' \
>   --data 'hosts=myrestapi.com' \
>   --data 'upstream_url=http://demo1592110.mockable.io/hello'

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 08 Dec 2017 09:25:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: kong/0.11.2

{"created_at":1512725135862,"strip_uri":true,"id":"d066b086-6d64-45b7-9908-f6411c456ce4","hosts":["myrestapi.com"],"name":"myRESTapi","http_if_terminated":false,"preserve_host":false,"upstream_url":"http://demo1592110.mockable.io/hello","upstream_connect_timeout":60000,"upstream_send_timeout":60000,"upstream_read_timeout":60000,"retries":5,"https_only":false}
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-102 ~]$

I am invoking that API through curl command in linux instance as below

curl -i -X GET \

> --url http://localhost:8000/ \
>   --header 'Host: myrestapi.com'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 49
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-origin: *
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 7806a9e612e31e610f9278b98371a60e
Date: Fri, 08 Dec 2017 09:26:55 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 227
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 46
Via: kong/0.11.2

{
"msg": "shruthi mock API"
}

i want to know how to invoke this api through web browser which should pass through kong in another machine.

i can directly execute through upstream url in browser : http://demo1592110.mockable.io/hello

but i want to hit kong and inturn want to invoke my api, but not using curl command, but directly want to achieve this through web browser.

i am new to kong, not sure if this is valid or not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "hosts" approach you need to pass the host in the header value which you cannot replicate from browser directly. For hosts approach you need to use any rest client to pass header value or programatically achieve it.

But as you mentioned you need to try it using browser directly, then I suggest you to use the "uris" when adding api to kong.

```
curl -i -X POST \
--url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \ 
--data "name=myRESTapi" \ 
--data "uris=/hello" \ 
--data "upstream_url=http://demo1592110.mockable.io"
```

You can see 'uris' added and URI from upstream_url is removed. No need of hosts after that.

Now if you hit the url in browser as

```
http://localhost:8000/hello
```

You can achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you, will try this. Then what is the significance of hosts property in Kong in real time?

Comment: That can be used when you are planning to call Kong server programatically and don't want users to be aware of you URIs. But with that you are restricted to add different hosts. I am using URI approach for our gateway which will keep us free from adding any new host. For kong we registered the Domain name so that has become host for us for all the calls.